# Quark Exchange Feynman Diagram

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

Consider the reaction $p^{+} + \pi ^{-} \to n + \pi^{0}$, or in terms of quarks $(uud) + (du^{*}) \to (udd) + (uu^{*})$. The reaction is just a quark exchange $u \iff d$. Is this how I draw a Feynman diagram for a quark exchange:

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: No, you got the basics wrong. Your quark lines miss the arrows.
And a quark cannot change (e.g. from $u$ to $d$) along a line,
when emitting/absorbing a gluon.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch How would I draw the Feynman diagram for this reaction?

Comment: You need to draw all 5 quark/antiquark lines ($u$, $u$, $d$, $d$, $\bar u$):
the 4 quark lines with arrow pointing to the right,
and the 1 anti-quark line with arrow pointing to the left.
Then look where you need to put gluon lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Feynman diagram for the reaction
$$p^{+} + \pi ^{-} \to n + \pi^{0}$$
or in terms of quarks
$$(uud) + (d\bar{u}) \to (udd) + (u\bar{u})$$
you need to draw all 5 quark/antiquarks.

The reaction is essentially the exchange of
an $u$ and a $d$ quark between the two composites.

[image: Feynman diagram]

Notice the following features, all arising
from the Feynman rules of quantum chromodynamics
(the theory of quarks and gluons):

- Quarks ($u$, $d$) are represented by lines
  with an arrow pointing from past to future.
- An antiquark ($\bar u$) is represented by a line
  with an arrow pointing from future to past.
- When a quark leaves its composite or merges
  with another composite, this is accompanied
  by the emission/absorption of a gluon ($g$).
- The emission/absorption of a gluon does not
  change the flavor of the quark, i.e.
  $u$ stays $u$, and $d$ stays $d$.

The last of the features above makes that
the Feynman diagram looks different from the one
shown in your question.